# Problem with mongodb-memory-server buildup and teardown in Jasmine beforeEach and afterEach

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jasmine

I'm testing Node/Express create endpoints, and I'm using mongodb-memory-server for the in-memory database - but I'm having problems with setup. Here are my helper methods.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { MongoMemoryServer } = require("mongodb-memory-server");

let mongo = null;

const testConnect = async () => {
    mongo = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
    const uri = mongo.getUri();
    await mongoose.connect(uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
};

const testClose = async () => {
    await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();
    await mongoose.connection.close();
    await mongo.stop();
}

const testClear = async () => {
    const collections = mongoose.connection.collections;
    for (const key in collections) {
        const collection = collections[key];
        await collection.deleteMany();
    }
}

module.exports = { testConnect, testClear, testClose }
```

Anyway, I'm running the `testConnect` method in the `beforeAll` and the `testClose` method in the `afterAll`, and they seem to work - but the `testClear` is problematic.

```
const supertest = require("supertest");
const app = require("../../../src/app");
const request = supertest(app);
const iMDT = require("../../support/database/database.support");
const Property = require("../../../src/models/property.model");
const errors = require("../../../src/support/dictionaries/errors.dictionary");
const testProperty = {
    key: "bestCity",
    value: "Lahaina"
};
describe("Property -> create: ", () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {
        await iMDT.testConnect();
    });
    beforeEach(async () => {
        await iMDT.testClear();
    });
    it("Should create a Property with valid values.", async () => {
        return request.post("/properties").send(testProperty).then((res) => {
            expect(res.body.key).toBe(testProperty.key);
            expect(res.body.value).toBe(testProperty.value);
        });
    });
    it("Should create an error in the case of a duplicate key.", async () => {
        const model = new Property(testProperty);
        model.save().then((prop) => {
            return request.post("/properties").send(testProperty).then((res) => {
                console.log(res.body);
                expect(res.body.errors[0].key).toBe(errors.getPropertyCreationErrorMessages().keyIsADuplicate);
            });
        });
    });
    it("Should create a Property with valid values.", async () => {
        return request.post("/properties").send(testProperty).then((res) => {
            console.log(res.body);
            expect(res.body.key).toBe(testProperty.key);
            expect(res.body.value).toBe(testProperty.value);
        });
    });
    afterEach(() => {
        return iMDT.testClear().then((res) => {
        });
    });
    afterAll(async () => {
        await iMDT.testClose();
    });
});
```

But the behavior is odd; when I comment out the `beforeEach`, the second creation spec fails, logging the same "duplicate key" error; it seems like the clearing routine after the tests isn't running - even though I log the result object, and it confirms the right amount of records are removed.

Then, when I comment out the `afterEach` and return the `beforeEach`, the second creation test succeeds, but the DUPLICATE spec fails, returning the created object in the body instead of the expected error. The manual save is AFTER the clearing routine, so it should be there to trigger the duplicate error, but it's like it's not in the system.

I've turned off the random flag in my Jasmine config file; does anyone have any other ideas about what could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `exec` function returns an actual Promise, where normal queries just return a thenable, so calling the function provides greater control and fixes this behavior.